# MRTK error: does not implement abstract member 'InputSystemGlobalHandlerListener.UnregisterHandlers()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm trying to test a very simple script to learn to use the input-action system in MRTK. I use a standard function to read the input, from a tutorial and also found on the MRTK documentation here: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityPointerHandler.html

However, the code below gives me a error that I cannot figure out....

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;


public class GameManager : BaseInputHandler, IMixedRealityPointerHandler
{
public MixedRealityInputAction Showmenu;
public Text ButtonText;
int clicktimes = 0;


// Start is called before the first frame update

public void ButtonClicker()
{
    clicktimes++;
    ButtonText.text = "You clicked: " + clicktimes.ToString();
}

public void OnPointerUp(MixedRealityPointerEventData pd)
{

}

public void OnPointerDown(MixedRealityPointerEventData pd)
{

}
public void OnPointerClicked(MixedRealityPointerEventData pd)
{

}
public void OnPointerDragged(MixedRealityPointerEventData pd)
{

}
```

}

The error is: CS0534    'GameManager' does not implement inherited abstract member 'InputSystemGlobalHandlerListener.UnregisterHandlers()'

Can't figure it out... any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me.... here is the answer in case it's useful to someone:

```
protected override void UnregisterHandlers()
{

}

protected override void RegisterHandlers()
{

}
```

Comment: Yea, just hover the mouse over that error and any IDE will tell you what to do ;) Altho the sentence "<class name> does not implement inherited abstract member <interace.method>" is quite clear :)